# C Loop Optimization

Tags: c, loops, optimization

Do you guys know how to optimize this loop? The array is of size of 10,000.

```
int *inlink_num = calloc(npages, sizeof(int))
int **inlink_index = calloc(npages, sizeof(int *));
int *outlink_num = calloc(npages, sizeof(int));

//there is an function to initialize above three variable


for (int i = 0; i < npages; i++)
{   
    for (int j = 0; j < inlink_num[i]; j++)
    {
        sum += (store_val[inlink_index[i][j]] / (double) outlink_num[inlink_index[i][j]]);
    }

    rank_val[i] =  constant_part + dampener * sum;
    convergence = rank_val[i] - store_val[i];
    threshold += (convergence * convergence);
    sum = 0.0;
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Changing `store_val` to an array of doubles might help.

Comment: How are `store_val`, `inlink_index` and `outlink_num` declared ?

Comment: How is `store_val` defined?

Comment: Declaring your pointers as `restrict` may help greatly.

Comment: Use pointers (which is sort of an iterator in C) ;-). Then: Optimization depends a the sizes here: If store_val is smaller than inlink_index: Create an array ratios which has the same length as store_val and first calculate ratios = store_val / outlink_num. Then perform the summation over ratios as above.

Comment: In any case you should compute `inlink_index[i]` once for each i, instead of indexing again and again for each j. (I'm not sure whether a compiler would realize its invariability.) If you don't trust your compiler you'd also compute `inlink_num[i]` outside the loop's condition.

Comment: Hi @Peter Schneider, it is a 2d array.

Comment: Yes. inlink_index[i] therefore is a onedimensional array, indexed only by j. The statement would be `int *inlinkVec = inlink_index[i];`, the use would be `store_val[inlinkVec[j]]`.

Comment: At some point SO will ask us to start a "conversation" which is fine. For now I'd like to know what "not gain" means. Not faster? And I'd follow Dan's advice if your compiler permits (google "C restrict" which points to non standard keywords for various compilers).

Comment: @PeterSchneider When I use linked list to solve the problem, it takes half of the time. However, when I use array, it doubles the time. In theory, using array should be faster than using linked list.

Comment: Not necessarily for sequential acccess (as opposed to random access, where lists suck). But: Did you measure times with 1. Your original code; 2. Dan's suggestion; 3. My suggestion; 4. A combination? What were the results?

Comment: @PeterSchneider **restrict** is a standard keyword in C.

Comment: @PeterSchneider I measure time with your suggestion. No gain.

Comment: @Lundin C99 which is not always available, hence the wikipedia hint.

Comment: And you _did_ assign the array outside the j loop (sorry to ask)? What about restrict? Post the changed code below your originals.

Comment: You question is inprecise. "Do you know how?" --> My valid answer: "Yes." :P

Comment: Isn't the code slow because it's buggy?  inlink_index an array of * int, but the calloc doesn't know any fixed size for each row, so what does inlink_index [i][j] actually mean?

Comment: I locate the problem. When the accessing store_val[inlink_index[i][j]], it is too slow. But how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

The normal assumption is that the inner loop is the only one worth optimising. Unfortunately what we seem to have is the size of the *outer* loop, being 10,000.

If performance on a loop of this kind is important enough to ask a question here and spend time looking at answers, then it is also important enough to do the first three things.

1. Benchmark. Assumed done.
2. Profile. Find out which lines of code are the performance bottleneck. Not done.
3. Examine generated code. See what the compiler generates. Not done.

So, please edit your question to provide this additional information.

Meanwhile, there are 3 broad strategies for improving the performance of this kind of program.

1. Change the algorithm. Find a different way to calculate the results and/or use more CPU cores.
2. Help the compiler. Make minor changes to the code so the compiler can optimise better.
3. Use the CPU better. Improve cache locality and/or enable better choice of instructions, such as SIMD.

More CPU cores means threading. Not easy, but for this kind of code potentially a 4x speed up.

Suggestions like RESTRICT help the compiler to detect and avoid aliasing. My guess is that this code is so simple the compiler does not need help there. Until you look at the generated code you won't know.

The pointer indirection at the heart of the loop looks guaranteed to break caching. Is a different data structure possible? A flat multidimensional array that fits in the L2 cache and has the right alignment properties would be the aim.

These are really just starting points. There is always a way to make the code run faster. If not, then just buy more hardware.

Answer (score 0):

How are you initialising the inlink_index array, what range is the j subscript?

If you're doing lookups on random index values off the end of the inlink_index array then your code is ultra-cache unfriendly and would be expected to run, not only incorrectly but very slowly.

If 0..j-1 is large and you don't care about the ordering of elements just looping over all of them, then arranging sorted data by index values would improve cache locality.

The code shown looks like it may not been converted from lists to array correctly :

```
int **inlink_index = calloc(npages, sizeof(int *));
...
for (int i = 0; i < npages; i++)
{   
    for (int j = 0; j < inlink_num[i]; j++)
    {
        sum += (store_val[inlink_index[i][j]] / (double) outlink_num[inlink_index[i][j]]);
    }
...
```

Bytes allocated for inlink_index is npages * (sizeof int *), so perhaps npages * 2 * 4 bytes (64bit pointers).  Now, i varies from 0.. npages-1, but only has sizeof int * bytes for each entry, not 0..max j-1.  How can that be correct?

If you want to use [i][j] to subscript into a flat array of int then, then fixed size needs to be defined, so a[i][j] = a + i*maxPossible(j) + j has a meaning.  So you would size the inlink_index as npages * maxPossible(j) * sizeof int.  But as shown, how can the compiler figure the size of each row out?

On other hand if j are variable length vectors, storing integers then you need to explicitly dereference `inlink_index[ i]` not treat it as a flat array :

```
int inlink_row[] = inlink_index[ i];  /* Set row slice to base of int array */
int index = inlink_row[ j];           /* Set int value */
```

That assumes code which assigns the address of an array of j elements to each inlink_index[ i] row.

I think, the subscript is simply doing pointer arithmetic `*( *(inlink_index + i) + j)` which is `inlink_index + i * sizeof(int*) + j * sizeof(int)` perhaps `inlink_index + i * 8 + j * 4 bytes` and isn't doing an expected pointer dereference.

Because char foo[2][4] assumes a contiguous memory allocation, [0][0], [0][1] .. [0][3], [1][0], .. [1][3].  `char **foo; foo[0] = "one"; foo[1] = strdup ("two");` does not have contiguous chars in memory.

Comment: I locate the problem. When the accessing store_val[inlink_index[i][j]], it is too slow. But how can I resolve it?

Comment: Why's the list faster? This inlink_index is effectively a pointer, so as constructed you aren't benefitting from array's implicit lists, where you know "this" is a[i] and "next" is a[i+1], "first" is a[0]. You need to step back, study the overal problem and probably organise the data, to maximise performance.  For instance, if inlink_index was sorted by value, the pre-fetch and cache would work well.

Comment: As currently constructed, your question isn't giving sufficient information.